# Charge renormalization point in massive abelian gauge theory

Tags: renormalization, symmetry-breaking, ward-identity

Let's assume massless QED. The [Ward identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ward%E2%80%93Takahashi_identity#The_Ward_identity) hold. Through this identity we determine the finite part of the counterterm when fix the value of electric charge to be the experimentally observed one:

The renormalized vertex function is $\bar{u}(p - q)\Gamma_{\mu}u(p)$ for process $e \to e +\gamma$, where the electron states are on shell and $q \to 0$ ($q$ denotes photon momentum) must correspond to $e_{phys}\bar{u}(p - q)\gamma_{\mu}u(p)$.

Let's now assume massive "QED" (mass is given to the photon through spontaneously broken symmetry). Suppose the mass of the "photon" is much larger than the electron one. The Ward identities still hold.

Do we still have to determine the finite part of the counterterm for $q \to 0$, or, by other words, does this condition correspond to experimental measuring of charge for a theory with spontaneously broken symmetry? Or do we have to use the other scale for $q$? Does the mass of "photon" generated by spontaneously broken symmetry affect on this physical scale?

Comment: 1. If the symmetry is broken, I don't see why the Ward identity should still hold, because it is a consequence of gauge invariance. 2. The scale $q$ at which we fix $e(q)$ to be $e_\text{phys}(q)$ is *always* arbitrary (you could as well fix it by measuring the phyiscal charge at $q = 1\text{TeV}$), so I don't know what you are asking.

Comment: @ACuriousMind : symmetry is broken not explicit, but spontaneously. So gauge invariance of theory is hold. This fact was used by Jackiw in his article http://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.8.2386 without derivation, and was proved by Nakanishi in following article:
http://ptp.oxfordjournals.org/content/51/4/1183.full.pdf .

Comment: As for the second remark, I've asked about fixing the value of physical charge. Its measuring corresponds to fixing scale of $q$. So by combining Ward identity with renormalization scale fixing we may determine the finite part of counterterm in theory. My question: is scale of measuring of charge changes when QED-like theory becomes spontaneously broken?

Comment: "...This fact...", - here I've meaned Ward identities.

Comment: Thanks for the Nakanishi article, very interesting! I'm afraid I still don't understand what you are asking because the renormalisation scale is *chosen* by us. There's nothing in the massless theory forcing us to do it at $q\to 0$, either, as far as I can see, it's just *convenient*.

Comment: @ACuriousaMind : I've incorrectly constructed the question. The main question is following: in QED experimantal measuring the charge corresponds to process $e \to e + \gamma$, where photon momentum is very small. By this definition, we hay straightforward determine the counterterm part, because Ward identities say to us that in this case vertex function is equal to $e_{exper.}\gamma_{\mu}$. If we choose the other scale, then we can't equal coefficient near $\gamma_{\mu}$ with given (!) experimental value (the continuation of comment will follow).

Comment: For example, SM generates counterterm of neutrino-photon interaction. We know that neutrino charge under EM group is zero, so the Ward identities gives a recipe of determination of finite part of counterterm: $\Gamma_{counterterm} + \Gamma_{loop} = 0$ for $q \to 0$, because charge is zero.

But let's have the case of spontaneously broken symmetry. Will $\Gamma_{counterterm} + \Gamma_{loop} = 0$ for $q \to 0$ still hold for neutrino-photon interaction? Or we need to choose the other scale for comparing $e$ with experiment?

Comment: Ah, I think I understand (and don't know that answer to that).